# How to convert a big csv file into json array quickly in java

Tags: java, json

I want to convert a big csv file like 20000 to 50000 record file into json array but it takes nearly 1 min to convert in is there any way to achieve it in less then 5 sec.

```
  ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("settings");
        String path = rb.getString("fileandfolder.Path");
        System.out.println(path + "ssdd");
        String csvPath = request.getParameter("DP") != null ? request
                .getParameter("DP").toString() : "";

        String orname = path + csvPath;
        File file = new File(orname);

        FileReader fin = new FileReader(file); //Read file one by one
        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(fin);

        int res;
        String csv = "";

        while ((res = fin.read()) != -1) {
            csv = csv + ((char) res); //Converted int to char and stored in csv

        }
        long start3 = System.nanoTime();
        JSONArray array = CDL.toJSONArray(csv);
        String Csvs = array.toString();

        long time3 = System.nanoTime() - start3;
        System.out
                .printf("Took %.3f seconds to convert to a %d MB file, rate: %.1f MB/s%n",
                        time3 / 1e9, file.length() >> 20, file.length()
                                * 1000.0 / time3);
```

Comment: Cvs library..??? can you show me any example of it.

Comment: i have removed it from the code it was not required any more.

Comment: Then change your code to reflect that, your code doesn't compile as it is. so `long time3 = System.nanoTime() - start2;` probably should be `long time3 = System.nanoTime() - start3;`

Comment: Note that by providing lots of unnecessary file reading code, which wasn't being timed (apparently), you've confused a lot of people here.

Comment: 50k entries in one network response sounds like a bad idea anyway.

Comment: Have you thought about using a library like opencsv: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No, I havent thought for it.

Comment: Another possibility is Jackson's CSV mapper: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/convert-csv-file-directly-to-json-file-using-jackson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two glaring performance problems in your code, both of them in this snippet:

```
    while ((res = fin.read()) != -1) {
        csv = csv + ((char) res);
    }
```

First problem: `fin` is an unbuffered `FileReader`, so each `read()` call is actually doing a system call.  Each syscall is hundreds or even thousands of instructions.  And you are doing that for each and every character in the input file.

Remedy: Read from `bi` rather than from `fin`.  (That's what you created it for ... presumably.)

Second problem: each time you execute `csv = csv + ((char) res);` you are creating a new String that is one character longer than the previous one.  If you have `N` characters in your input file, you end up copying roughly `N^2` characters to build the string.

Remedy: Instead of concatenating Strings, use a StringBuilder ... like this:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ....
        sb.append((char) res);
    ....
    String csv = sb.toString();
```

---

At this point, it is not clear to me if there is also a performance problem in converting the `csv` string to JSON; i.e. in this snippet.

```
    JSONArray array = CDL.toJSONArray(csv);
    String Csvs = array.toString();
```

Unfortunately, we don't know what `JSONArray` and `CDL` classes you are actually using.  Hence, it is difficult to say why they are slow, or whether there is a faster way to do the conversion.  (But I suspect, that the biggest performance problems are in the earlier snippet.)

Comment: Unless we find out where `start2` is initialized, that might not be the problem.

Comment: Yea ... the timing code is rather mucked up too. But I am prepared to accept that the OP's code really does take *minutes* to process a large file.  The performance problems are real.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((res = fin.read()) != -1) {
    sb.append((char) res); //Converted int to char and stored in csv
}
String csv = sb.toString();
```

Concating strings using + is slow, you should use StringBuilfer or StringBuffer

Comment: He isn't timing reading in the data, he is only timing the conversion of the string to the array

Comment: That still won't help, the time he's checking is the process of taking the `String` into a `JSONArray`.

Comment: @mikea before you down vote mine too, note OP is using `start2` for the timing, not `start3`

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Not true, `long start3 = System.nanoTime();` is not used in time calculation.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau unless he removed a line, I know it's above that loop for reading the file one character at a time.

Answer (score -1):

This `csv = csv + ((char) res)` is very slow, you are reading one char at a time, then allocating a new string with the old string and the new char.

To load all text from a file into a string do this:

```
static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
  throws IOException 
{
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
  return new String(encoded, encoding);
}
```

(from https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/360211, note there is a cleaner way if using java 7)

Use like this instead of loop:

```
String csv = readFile(orname, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Check what is being timed, that is not the problem.

Comment: As per the other answer, he isn't timing this section of the code

Comment: @mikea as per the other answer, he's timing from `start2` not `start3`.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau I did check. he's timing from `start2` not `start3`. It's a good guess that's in a line above the section copied.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this as "not useful", guess what code turned out to be slow in the end on the accepted answer, that loop.