# I am getting this error while converting csv to json schema by using this code

Tags: java, json, csv, mapping, converters

```
MappingIterator<Map<?, ?>> mappingIterator = csvMapper.reader(Map.class).with(bootstrap).readValue(file.getInputStream());
```

Above code throws this error:

```
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because the method to get MappingIterator is readValues instead of readValue.

The second method "readValue" (without 's') is used to read a single value from the schema.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with an example I got from [directly convert CSV file to JSON file using the Jackson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/convert-csv-file-directly-to-json-file-using-jackson-library)

Which version of the jackson databind and dataformat libraries are you using? There is a method `readValues(InputStream)` that returns a `MappingIterator`. But it seems there were a few changes in that area between the versions.

Answer (score 0):

The code `csvMapper.reader(Map.class).with(bootstrap).readValue(file.getInputStream());` returns `LinkedHashMap`. But `MappingIterator` cannot hold `LinkedHashMap`.

Not sure though, but try explicitly casting as shown below:

```
(MappingIterator)(csvMapper.reader(Map.class).with(bootstrap).readValue(file.getInputStream()));
```