# convert CSV file to JSON in java

Tags: java, json, csv

- This is my CSV file:

  ```
  no    name    id
  1     yog     a122
  2     nik     b122
  ```
- I want convert this file in json using java. I tried javascript, jsp,
  servlet but didn't get output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bit more googling on this, that is pretty much famous question.

Please check following link

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv

And also following stack overflow post

[directly convert CSV file to JSON file using the Jackson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/convert-csv-file-directly-to-json-file-using-jackson-library)