# convert csv to json using jackson

Tags: json, csv, jackson, apache-camel

not done this before. looking for a little direction and help. thanks all.

I need to take a csv data file and convert it to a json file of specific format. I'm reading up on JsonObject and JsonArray right now, ... thanks!

I have something like this.

```
timestamp,NST_MD3_CRANK_CASE,NST_MD3-TAH-0001,NST_MD3-TAH-0002,NST_MD3-TAH-0003,NST_MD3-TAH-0004,NST_MD3-TAH-0005,NST_MD3-TAH-0006,NST_MD3-TAH-0007,NST_MD3-TAH-0008,NST_MD3-TAH-0009,NST_MD3-TAH-0010,NST_MD3-TAH-0011,NST...
4/10/2018 7:55:10 PM,101,261,258,276,267,274,279,273,286,273,276,288,292,268,297,285,316,81,136,100,0,0,388,395,84,956,20,1,0,100,0,17,0,31,16,31,18,23,694.7667,59.98439,0,0,0,1,14998,13,24
4/10/2018 7:58:10 PM,101,261,258,276,267,274,279,273,286,273,276,288,292,268,297,285,316,81,136,100,0,0,388,395,84,956,20,1,0,100,0,17,0,31,16,31,18,23,694.9326,59.92459,0,0,0,1,14998,13,24
```

And I need it in a Json format like this...

```
{ "tags": [ {"tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE","data":[ {"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"}] }, ... ] }
```

I am using camel, java and jackson. thanks again!

Comment: I think you should check this question:
[directly convert CSV file to JSON file using the Jackson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/directly-convert-csv-file-to-json-file-using-the-jackson-library)

Comment: thans Artemis, good, but doesn't fit my implementation, thinking more towards the use of JsonObject, JsonArray, JsonFactory, writter etc.. doesn't cover creating a specific structure, at least that I'm aware. thanks for your answer.

Comment: I intend to use the splitter EIP, store the header, build the data into it, then map to Json. at least that's what I'm thinking out of the gate.

Comment: I'm hoping to get some feel on how to build a json structure like: {  
   "tags" : [  

{"tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE","data":[{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"}]}, learning json objects and json arrays.  <object> string : value=array
   <array>      object : string
      <object>  string= array
         <array>
           <object>
   list of name:values
           </object>
         </array>
      </object>
   </array>
</object>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jackson libraries, I figured out how to implement this in a stepwise fasion, using JsonFactory and JsonGenerator. thank you everybody.

Code:

```
public class JsonMapper implements Processor {

    private int noOfRows = 0;  //does not include the header record
    private int noOfColumns = 0;  //includes timestamp field

    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JsonMapper.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        log.info("Entering Json Mapper Processor...");

        String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        List<String> serviceRecords = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(body.split(System.lineSeparator())));
        noOfRows = serviceRecords.size() - 1;
        noOfColumns = getColumns(serviceRecords);
        StringBuilder header = getHeader( serviceRecords );
        serviceRecords.remove(0); //remove header record only data records in list
        String hdr[] = header.toString().split(",");
        //Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT1_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT2_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT3_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT4_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT5_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT6_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT7_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MUDPIT8_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_R_MUDPIT1_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_R_MUDPIT2_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_R_MUDPIT3_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_R_MUDPIT4_VOL,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_MOT_RUN_001,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_021,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_023,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_022,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_004,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_005,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_006,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_031,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_033,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_032,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_011,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_012,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_AI_013,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_MOT_RUN_010,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_MOT_RUN_004,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_MOT_RUN_005,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_MOT_RUN_006,Noble_nst_mud-pump-2_NST_MP2_MOT_RUN_009
        //04/10/2018 07:55:10 PM, 1, 0, 2, 0, 81, 64, 64, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 289.4146, 288.65, 288.65, 0, 0, 0, 288.9146, 291.15, 289.2283, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        //String [] record = serviceRecords.toArray(new String[serviceRecords.size()]);

        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(sw);
        generator.setPrettyPrinter(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());

        generator.writeStartObject();  // {
        generator.writeFieldName("tags"); // {"tags":
        generator.writeStartArray(); // {"tags": [

        for ( String rec : serviceRecords ) {
            String[] data = rec.split(",");

            for ( int i = 0; i < (noOfColumns - 1); ++i ) {  //header has 1 less field than data record         
                generator.writeStartObject(); // {
                generator.writeStringField("tagId", hdr[i].trim()); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE" 
                generator.writeFieldName("data"); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data"
                generator.writeStartArray(); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [
                generator.writeStartObject(); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{
                generator.writeStringField("ts", data[0].trim()); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00"
                generator.writeStringField("v", data[i+1].trim()); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100"
                generator.writeStringField("q", "3"); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"
                generator.writeEndObject(); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"}
                generator.writeEndArray();  // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"}]
                generator.writeEndObject(); // { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"}]}
            }
        }
        generator.writeEndArray(); // {"tags": [ { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"}]} ]
        generator.writeEndObject();  // {"tags": [ { "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE", "data" : [{"ts":"2017-11-15T19:55:00","v" : "100","q":"3"}]} ]}
        generator.flush();
        generator.close();

        log.info("JSON: " + sw.toString());

        exchange.getIn().setBody(sw.toString());
        sw.close();
        log.info("Leaving Json Mapper Processor...");

   }

    public StringBuilder getHeader(List<String> serviceRecords) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
            log.debug( "count: " + i + " record: : " + serviceRecords.get(i).toString() );
            if ( i == 0 ) {
                String[] sa = serviceRecords.get(i).toString().split(",");
                for ( int j = 0; j < sa.length; ++j) {
                    if ( j != 0 ) {
                        sb.append(sa[j]).append(",");
                    }
                }
                sb.deleteCharAt(sb.lastIndexOf(",", sb.length())); 
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return sb;
    }

    public int getColumns(List<String> serviceRecords) {
        int columns = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 1; i++ ) {
            log.debug( "count: " + i + " record: : " + serviceRecords.get(i).toString() );
            if ( i == 0 ) {
                String[] sa = serviceRecords.get(i).toString().split(",");
                columns = sa.length;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        return columns;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is it using org.json: if you need to add more data just add more objects (data2,data3...) to JSONArray. Be careful with parenthesis while working with JsonArrays!

Expected output:

```
{
"tags": [{
    "data": [{
        "q": "3",
        "v": "100",
        "ts": "2017-11-15T19:55:00"
    }],
    "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE"
}]
```

}

here is the code:

```
package test;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class jsonExample {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create our data
        String tagId = "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE";
        JSONObject data1 = new JSONObject();        
        data1.put("ts", "2017-11-15T19:55:00");
        data1.put("v", "100");
        data1.put("q", "3");

        //create dataArray -> JSONArray
        /*
          [{ "ts": "2017-11-15T19:55:00",
             "v": "100",
             "q": "3" }] 
         */
        JSONArray dataArray = new JSONArray();
        dataArray.put(data1);

        //create internal JSON Object
        /*  
          {
            "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE",
            "data": [{
                "ts": "2017-11-15T19:55:00",
                "v": "100",
                "q": "3"
            }]
        }
         */
        JSONObject internal = new JSONObject();
        internal.put("tagId", tagId);
        internal.put("data", dataArray);

        //create tags -> JSON Array
        /*  
            [{
                "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE",
                "data": [{
                    "ts": "2017-11-15T19:55:00",
                    "v": "100",
                    "q": "3"
                }]
            }]
         */
        JSONArray tags = new JSONArray();
        tags.put(internal);

        //create final JSON Object
        /*
          {
            "tags": [{
                "tagId": "NST_MD1_CRANK_CASE",
                "data": [{
                    "ts": "2017-11-15T19:55:00",
                    "v": "100",
                    "q": "3"
                }]
            }]
         }
         */
        JSONObject finalJson = new JSONObject();
        finalJson.put("tags", tags);
        System.out.println(finalJson.toString());

    }


}
```

Comment: thank you Artemis, still playing around with java json classes, learning these new classes for me. greatly appreciate your help. this looks fairly straight forward, thanks

Comment: Is there a Maven dependency to use these Json packages to put in the POM so these can be imported?

Comment: it looks that Jackson is what is available for me to use. Jackson appears to be much more complicated than these libraries. do you know how to put this in Jackson?

Comment: thanks Artemis, I wish I could've used your libraries but your answer paved the way for me to accomplish this with Jackson.  I've accepted your answer.