# Convert CSV data into nested json objects using java library

Tags: json, csv

I am searching for java library that can convert csv data which consists nested objects (like : address.city, address.country) to convert into json data with nested objects accordingly.
Below is the java code i am using:

```
File input = new File("input.csv");
File output = new File("output.json");

CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder()
.setUseHeader(true).build();
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

    // Read data from CSV file
    List<Object> readAll = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();
    System.out.println(readAll);
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Write JSON formated data to output.json file
    mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(output, readAll);

    // Write JSON formated data to stdout
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(readAll));
```

This is the output i am getting:

```
[ {
 "studentName" : "Foo",
 "Age" : "12",
 "address__city" : "newyork",
 "address__address1" : "North avenue",
 "address__zipcode" : "123213",
 "subjects__name" : "English",
 "subjects__marks" : "40"
  }, {
 "studentName" : "ABcd",
 "Age" : "25",
 "address__city" : "achi",
 "address__address1" : "Morh",
 "address__zipcode" : "27400",
 "subjects__name" : "History",
 "subjects__marks" : "50"
 } ]
```

This is expected output:

```
{
"studentName": "Foo",
"Age": "12",
"address":{
    "city" : "newyork",
    "address1": "North avenue",
    "zipcode" : "123213"
},
"subjects": [
    {
        "name": "English",
        "marks": "40"
    },
    {
        "name": "History",
        "marks": "50"
    }
]
}
```

This is input csv:

```
"studentName","Age","address__city","address__address1","address__zipcode","subjects__name","subjects__marks"
"Foo","12","newyork","North avenue","123213","English","40"
"","25","achi","Morh","2400","History","
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/directly-convert-csv-file-to-json-file-using-the-jackson-library]

Comment: Thanks for the time @shas, but i am still getting the same output as it was...
i am not getting the expected output...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/java_beans.html#nested-classes) can do what you need on the CSV side with its `@Nested` annotation.

It doesn't work to read/write JSON though. So my advice is to use univocity parsers to parse your CSV into the object structure you need, then Jackson to write that object structure into JSON.

Hope this helps.
Disclosure: I'm the author of univocity-parsers. It's open-source and free (Apache 2.0 license)

Comment: would you help me in this...?

Comment: @Jeronimo Backes, will the univocity parser be able to create subjects array in the above example using Nested annotation?