# Convert flattened CSV to nested JSON

Tags: java, univocity

I want to create a nested JSON from a flattened CSV:

CSV:

```
name address_city address_state
John Mumbai MH
John Bangalore KA
Bill Chennai TN
```

JSON:

```
[
 {
  "name": "John",
  "address": [
              {
               "city": "Mumbai",
               "state": "MH"
              },
              {
               "city": "Bangalore",
               "state": "KA"
             }
            ]
 },
 {
  "name": "Bill",
  "address": [
              {
               "city": "Chennai",
               "state": "TN"
              }
            ]
 }
]
```

I'm using univocity parser with @Nested annotation like this:

```
@Nested(headerTransformer = AddressTypeTransformer.class, args = "address")
private Address address;
```

and I'm getting JSON output as below, which has the address object and not array which is perfectly fine:

```
[
 {
  "name": "John",
  "address": {
               "city": "Mumbai",
               "state": "MH"
              }
 },
 {
  "name": "John",
  "address": {
               "city": "Mumbai",
               "state": "MH"
             }
 },
 {
  "name": "Bill",
  "address": {
               "city": "Chennai",
               "state": "TN"
              }
 }
]
```

But when i change the code to make the address as array:

```
@Nested(headerTransformer = AddressTypeTransformer.class, args = "address")
private Address[] address;
```

I get following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.univocity.parsers.common.DataProcessingException: Unable to instantiate class '[Lcom.ss.beans.Address;'
Internal state when error was thrown: line=2, column=0, record=1, charIndex=58, headers=[id, name, address_city, address_state],
```

Why the @Nested annotation is not working with arrays/lists?
How can I solve this problem?
Is there any other way to solve this problem without using univocity?

PS: I'm asking this question after following the reply from @Jeronimo Backes in this post:
[Convert CSV data into nested json objects using java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51890998/convert-csv-data-into-nested-json-objects-using-java-library)

Comment: Try a `List<Address>` instead

Comment: i tried that as well, but got same error

Comment: The `@Nested` annotation only operates on each row separately (like the working example you refer to in your question). It cannot combine data across rows. See the [Nested Classes documentation on this page](https://www.univocity.com/pages/java_beans.html#reading-data-into-java-beans).

Comment: I would read your data into a collection of interim Java objects, each containing `String name` and `Address address` and then I would process that collection through a Java collector. This is where the multiple addresses can be gathered into a list . Finally you can generate the JSON output from that resulting new collection.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks for the suggestion. I'm not much aware of Collectors, but I  tried using Collectors.groupingBy() but that didn't work. Can you please provide a snippet I can follow?

Comment: Understood about the "collector" approach. Sometimes I think it can be easier to just process the collections in the traditional way. I have provided some notes on that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

The test data (in my case, the fields are tab-separated):

```
name    address_city    address_state
John    Mumbai  MH
John    Bangalore   KA
Bill    Chennai TN
```

The imports I used:

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.univocity.parsers.common.processor.BeanListProcessor;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParser;
import com.univocity.parsers.csv.CsvParserSettings;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

The processing code:

```java
//
// parse the source file into a list of SourceRecord beans:
//
Reader reader = new FileReader(new File("C:/tmp/univocity_demo.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BeanListProcessor<SourceRecord> processor = new BeanListProcessor<>(SourceRecord.class);
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.getFormat().setDelimiter("\t"); // tab separated data
parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
parserSettings.setProcessor(processor);
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
parser.parse(reader);
List<SourceRecord> sourceRecords = processor.getBeans();

//
// process those SourceRecord objects into consolidated Name beans:
//
Map<String, Name> namesMap = new HashMap<>();
sourceRecords.forEach(sourceRecord -> {
    String sourceName = sourceRecord.getName();
    if (namesMap.containsKey(sourceName)) {
        namesMap.get(sourceName).getAddresses().add(sourceRecord.getAddress());
    } else {
        Name name = new Name();
        name.setName(sourceName);
        name.getAddresses().add(sourceRecord.getAddress());
        namesMap.put(sourceName, name);
    }
});

//
// convert to JSON:
///
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(namesMap.values());
```

The `SourceRecord` bean is as follows. Note that we do not need anything other than the basic `@Nested` annotation, here:

```java
public class SourceRecord {
    
    @Parsed(field = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @Nested
    private Address address;

    // getters/setters not shown

}
```

Here are the output `Name` and `Address` beans. Note I am using the field name `addresses` (not `address`) in the `Name` bean:

```java
public class Name {
    
    private String name;
    
    private final List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters/setters not shown
}
```

And the `Address` bean - this is used both for the final output and also when reading the source file (hence the annotations are needed):

```java
public class Address {
    
    @Parsed(field = "address_city")
    private String city;
    
    @Parsed(field = "address_state")
    private String state;

    // getters/setters not shown
    
}
```

The final JSON is:

```json
[{
    "name": "John",
    "addresses": [{
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "state": "MH"
    }, {
        "city": "Bangalore",
        "state": "KA"
    }]
}, {
    "name": "Bill",
    "addresses": [{
        "city": "Chennai",
        "state": "TN"
    }]
}]
```