# Parsing JSON with a random field (java)

Tags: java, json, firebase, csv, gson

I want to convert a `JSON` file into a `CSV` file.

My `JSON` file comes from a `DataBase` stored in `Firebase` and has an structure like this:

```
{
  "PATIENT" : {
     "-LbhwHC7Y6_umc" : {
       "age" : 31,
       "name" : "Phoebe"
    },
    "-LbhwTFJ6xjEf" : {
      "age" : 20,
      "name" : "Amy"
    },
    "-LbhxUmJ_dwIC" : {
      "age" : 28,
      "name" : "Joe"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to do it with `Gson`:

```
package Parser;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how to create a `JSON` object with random fields like:

"-LbhwHC7Y6_umc", "-LbhwTFJ6xjEf" and "-LbhxUmJ_dwIC"

generated by Firebase

Comment: The PATIENT field just needs to be a `Map<String, Person>`

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a map of strings to objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Jackson` library you have already mapper for `JSON` and `CSV` in one library. Simple example which reads your `JSOn` and generate `CSV`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SequenceWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        // read JSON
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonFile);
        JsonNode patient = root.get("PATIENT");

        // Write CSV
        CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder()
                .addColumn("age", CsvSchema.ColumnType.NUMBER)
                .addColumn("name")
                .setUseHeader(true)
                .build();
        try (SequenceWriter sequenceWriter = csvMapper.writer().with(schema).writeValues(System.out)) {
            patient.elements().forEachRemaining(node -> {
                try {
                    sequenceWriter.write(node);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
age,name
31,Phoebe
20,Amy
28,Joe
```

Generally, when you have random keys in `JSON` payload you can deserialise it to `Map<String, Object>` in `Jackson` and `Gson` libraries.

See aslo:

- [jackson-dataformats-text - CSV](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv)
- [jackson-databind - JSON](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind)

Comment: Hi, what if I have to take columns that are nested objet incide the jsonObject , example :
 [{"field1":"1","field2":[{"date1":[{"key1":1},{"key2":3},{"key3":4}]}],"field3":"A","field4":"X","field4":"XX","field4":"B"}]

i want to take date1 also as column

Comment: @Ussopokingo, generally it depends from the `CSV` format you want to achieve.  You need to create new question (with link to this), provide example `JSON` payload and example `CSV` output and libraries you want to use. In this case `Jackson` I believe and someone should help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is easiest to just model Java DTO classes holding the data.

So in your JSON you have an object -let us say wrapper -that contains another object having label `PATIENT`. And because the fields that `PATIENT` has are arbitrary names AND it also seems that the data each field contain is actually the **Patient** it thus suggest that `PATIENT` is a `Map` having those arbitrary field names as the keys and  instances of patienta as the values of each entry.

So the Wrapper would be like:

```
@Getter
public class Wrapper {
    // We want the correct notation & plural, of course
    @SerializedName("PATIENT") 
    private Map<String, Patient> patients;
}
```

The Patient would be then like:

```
@Getter
public class Patient {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

Deserialisation nad using  would then be something like:

```
Wrapper w = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("c:\\file.json"), Wrapper.class );
w.getPatients().keySet().... // or however it is most comfortable
```