# CSV to nested Json convert in java

Tags: json, csv, nested, converters, csvtojson

I need to convert CSV file into nested json format as like below.

```
netgroup =
 "literals": [
    {
      "type": "Network",
      "value": "10.0.0.0/8"
    },
    {
      "type": "Host",
      "value": "10.0.0.27"
    },
    {
      "type": "Host",
      "value": "10.0.0.28"
    }
  ],
  "name": "network_group_3"
}
```

Please help me on this.. I can ready to keep CSV file as any format..

Comment: What is the CSV format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [directly convert CSV file to JSON file using the Jackson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/directly-convert-csv-file-to-json-file-using-the-jackson-library)