# How do I quickly convert this fixed width TXT to JSON with Sublime or another text editor

Tags: json, csv, sublimetext3, txt

```
ID NUMBER    LAST NAME        FIRST NAME     COUNTY     CITY       ZIP ST SEX BIRTH DATE EXPIRATION ID ISSUE ST
```

I took that and used multiline edit to make it

```
ID NUMBER,    LAST NAME,        FIRST NAME     ,COUNTY     ,CITY       ,ZIP ,ST,SEX,BIRTH DATE,EXPIRATION, ID ISSUE, ST
```

how do I convert it to JSON quickly?

(I am told that I can't use a website to do it because the data is sensitive)
(the data under each column has been removed for security)

Comment: Do you know any programming languages? It would be much easier to do in Python, for example.

Comment: Since you already converter `TXT` file to `CSV` comma separated file you can take a look at [directly convert CSV file to JSON file using the Jackson library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766266/directly-convert-csv-file-to-json-file-using-the-jackson-library/19766556#19766556) and using `Jackson` and `Java` convert it to a `JSON`.

Comment: @MichałZiober FWF is not CSV at all. Usually FWF value contains space and not distinguishable fro delimiter.