# Convert CSV with nested JSON object to JSON

Tags: java, json, csv, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I have a sample CSV message:

```
header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null}
```

How to convert it in form of embedded `JSON` as in:

```json
{
  "header1": "value1",
  "header2": "value2",
  "header3": "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"car\":null}"
}
```

I am using `Jackson` schema builder with default column separator:

```java
CsvSchema.builder().disableQuoteChar().setUseHeader(true).build();
CsvMapper.builder().enable(CsvParser.Feature.IGNORE_TRAILING_UNMAPPABLE, CsvParser.Feature.WRAP_AS_ARRAY).build();
```

Comment: Your CSV is broken. You need to change it a little bit. Wrap internal `JSON` with an escaping character. For example you can set apostrophe (') or pipe(|). Read `CSV` file, replace `{` with `|{` and `}` with `}|` and `CsvMapper` should handle it. For a general solution take a look at this question: [directly convert CSV file to JSON file using the Jackson library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19766266/51591)

Comment: @MichałZiober, Even if the CSV gets updated, how could I escape csv and json at the same time without changing column separator  from  ','?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presented `CSV` content is broken. Values which contains column separator should be wrapped with a quote character. If we can not change the app which generates it we need to amend it before deserialising process. This example is simple so we can just replace `{` with `|{` and `}` with `}|` and set `|` as a quote character. But for `JSON` payloads with internal objects we need to replace only the first `{` and the last `}` brackets. Code could look like below:

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CsvApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File csvFile = new File("./resource/test.csv").getAbsoluteFile();
        String csv = Files.readAllLines(csvFile.toPath()).stream().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
        csv = csv.replace("{", "|{").replace("}", "}|");

        CsvMapper csvMapper = CsvMapper.builder().build();

        CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setQuoteChar('|').setUseHeader(true).build();
        Object csvContent = csvMapper.readerFor(JsonNode.class).with(csvSchema).readValue(csv);

        JsonMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).build();
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, csvContent);
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```json
{
  "header1" : "value1",
  "header2" : "value2",
  "header3" : "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"car\":null}"
}
```

Comment: Do we need to build  a regex for nested JSON  to identify first and last '{' '}'  and that will again  fail if we will have  multiple nested JSONs?

Comment: Do not use `Regex` here. Just [StringUtils.lastIndexOf](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#lastIndexOf-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [RegExUtils.replaceFirst](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RegExUtils.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.util.regex.Pattern-java.lang.String-)

Comment: But what if we have multiple json as values?

Comment: @VaibhavTiwari, then you need to process it line by line. I assume that each line contains the whole `JSON` and there is no new lines inside. In case not, you need to handle this. Generally this is not a valid `CSV` file and handling all corner cases is painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a csv JS library such as json-2-csv

```js
# Global so it can be called from anywhere
npm install -g json2csv

# or as a dependency of a project
npm install json2csv --save
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `org.json.CDL` as follows:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
        String csvAsString = br.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        String json = CDL.toJSONArray(csvAsString).toString();
        try {
            Files.write(Path.of("src/main/resources/output.json"), json.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```